# generate complete call hierarchy in a treeview

Tags: java, c#

I have inherited a huge C# program and an even bigger Java (2 million+ lines) program.  In both projects I need to understand the code.  I'd like a treeview of the complete call hierarchy.  I know about Call hierarchy in eclipse and visual studio.  That is insufficient.  Those only go forward interactively and would take forever to see the complete tree.  There is no "expand all" command.  I don't want a graphical display as it would be too enormous.  Typically I build my own in excel but these projects are just too big to do that.  I've googled for hours with no luck.  Surely there must be a free tool available?  Any suggestions?

Comment: As you say, it would be too big to make sense of. What I would do is run it, and step through various parts of it. Having done this in the past, there's no silver bullet. It has taken me months to get to the point where I understood something well enough to dare to try fixing it.

Comment: sounds like you would benefit from the same tool I'm looking for.  The closest I've seen is IntelliJ but we are not allowed to use it over Eclipse.

Comment: You want simply program that can simply explain projects with words? I am a bit confused about what you want. But if you answered yes for this question, then nothing like that exists.

Comment: My grad training was in A.I. so I'm used to thinking of this as an information-processing problem. There is no program yet as smart as a human in the programming domain. This is a problem of reverse-engineering a mountain of code to get its connections to the problems it is solving. The best tool, so far, is brainware. To make an automated tool to do that is a worthy research problem. If you're up for that, by all means, go to it! (Remember Piet Hein: "Problems worthy of attack prove their worth by hitting back.")

Comment: Call hierarchy in eclipse and visual studio works well, given a specific call.  All I'm looking for is a program that does the same thing only for every call in every package, and put the whole thing in a tree view so you can navigate from the top main() call to everything underneath.  No AI needed.